# Header and footer not aligning with main body on mobile site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an assignment to build a fully responsive website, however I've ran into some issues with the mobile design of the website. When I change the dimensions of the site to mobile, such as an iphone 12, the header and footer doesn't align with the main body. For example, the main menu extends past the main body hiding the hamburger menu bar. You could only access it if you scroll to the right. Next, the footer doesn't seem to be aligning properly with the main body as well. There is also a lot of extra white space on the right hand side of the mobile site. I've tried to minimize the text in the footer, but this didn't work out. I'm really stuck here and I don't want to re-build the site again.

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: <900>;
  font-style: normal;
}

nav {
  background-color: hsl(220deg 100% 80%);
  box-shadow: hsl(220deg 60% 50%);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav ul li {
  color: #808080;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 300px;
}

.nav-btn {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-btn img {
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -10px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(#c9d0ff 0%, #d3ecff 50%);
  padding: 0 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #C04848;
  background: linear-gradient(#c9d0ff 0%, #d3ecff 50%), url("main.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.header h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 3vw;
  line-height: 3.5vw;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

nav.fixedToTop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/* add space for fixed header when it's fixed to top */

nav.fixedToTop+.content {
  margin-top: 8rem;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}


/*<------------------------------- FOOTER ------------------------------>*/

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100% height: auto;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

footer .container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

footer .container .sec h3 {
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

footer .container .sec p {
  color: #555;
}

footer .container .sci {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px);
}

footer .container .sci li {
  list-style: none;
}

footer .container .sci li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #333;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer .container .sci img {
  color: #fff;
}

footer .container .quicklinks {
  position: relative;
}

footer .container .quicklinks ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

footer .container .quicklinks ul li a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

footer .container .contact .info {
  position: relative;
}

footer .container .contact .info li {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

footer .container .contact .info li span {
  color: #555;
}

footer .container .contact .info li a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copyrightText {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 100px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

@media (max-width: 991) {
  footer {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  footer .container {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
  }
  .copyrightText {
    padding: 20px 40px 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  footer .container {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
  }
}


/*<------------------------------- END OF FOOTER ------------------------------>*/


/* ------------- Media Queries for navbar ---------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #0000ff;
    top: 2.5rem;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
    overflow: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top .4s, opacity .3s;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding: 1.25rem 1.5rem;
    display: inline-grid;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: background-color .3s;
  }
  .nav ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .nav ul:hover {
    background-color: ;
  }
  .show-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 3.5rem;
    pointer-events: initial;
  }
  .menu-links {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  nav.logo {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
  }
  .show-menu {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
}


}

/*---------- Media Queries for header content --------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .header {
    min-height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .user-img {
    width: 100%;
    right: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html" lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="main" href="main.js">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <img src="" alt="" class="logo">
    <ul id="menu-links">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Courses</li>
      <li>Pricing</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="nav-btn">Get Started </button>
    <img src="menu.png" alt="" class="menu-icon" onclick="toggleMenu()">
  </nav>


  <div class="header">
    <h1>JOIN US<br>TODAY!</h1>
    <img src="main.png" alt="" class="user-img">
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sec aboutus">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque placerat quam vel est sodales hendrerit ac sit amet augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Pellentesque ipsum enim, venenatis
          at sem ac, facilisis suscipit sapien. </p>
        <ul class="sci">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="instagram.png" alt="instagram"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="youtube.png" alt="youtube"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="sec quicklinks">
        <h3>Support</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="sec quicklinks">
        <h3>Shop</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One-on-one</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="sec contact">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul class="info">
          <li>
            <span><img src="phone.png" rel="phone"><p><a href="#">+1 557 555 7256</a></p></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><img src="mail.png" rel="email"><p><a href="#">websitemaster@email.com</a></p></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


  </footer>
  <div class="copyrightText">
    <p>Copyright 2024 Online Tutorials. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    let menuLinks = document.getElementById("menu-links");

    function toggleMenu() {
      menuLinks.classList.toggle('show-menu');
    }

    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

    /* Get the header element and it's position */
    var headerDiv = document.querySelector("nav");
    var headerBottom = headerDiv.offsetTop + headerDiv.offsetHeight;

    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

      /* if scrolling down, let it scroll out of view as normal */
      if (prevScrollpos <= currentScrollPos) {
        headerDiv.classList.remove("fixedToTop");
        headerDiv.style.top = "-7.2rem";
      }
      /* otherwise if we're scrolling up, fix the nav to the top */
      else {
        headerDiv.classList.add("fixedToTop");
        headerDiv.style.top = "0";
      }

      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }

    /*=============== SHOW MENU ===============*/
    const showMenu = (toggleId, navId) => {
      const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
        nav = document.getElementById(navId)

      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Add show-menu class to nav menu
        nav.classList.toggle('show-menu')
        // Add show-icon to show and hide menu icon
        toggle.classList.toggle('show-icon')
      })
    }

    showMenu('menu-links', 'menu-links')
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Krystian728 please provide an example.

Comment: In your footer navbar media query try to use this code instead:

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    footer .container {
      width: 100%;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 20px;
    }
  }

Have changed the grid-column-template code to take only 1 column instead of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your footer navbar media query try to use this code instead:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    footer .container {
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 20px;
    }
}
```

Have changed the grid-column-template code to take only 1 column instead of 2.